# Is there any way of running this code without creating a loop

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons with Dynamically changing text which can lead to a different height of the Buttons, my code is trying to avoid this but is also creating a loop

```
    ViewTreeObserver observer= Button0.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    int HighestButton;
                    HighestButton = Button0.getHeight();
                    Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 0");
                    if(Button1.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button1.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 1");
                    }
                    if(Button2.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button2.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 2");
                    }
                    if(Button3.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button3.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 3");
                    }

                    Button0.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button1.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button2.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button3.setHeight(HighestButton);

                }
            });
```

Comment: separately add observer on your buttons and remove it inside if condition

Comment: A possible alternative: set a maximum text length, and truncate (with ellipsis...) if the text is longer than the maximum.  That will limit the variation in button size.

Comment: The fact you need this code is a problem in and of itself.  Make a LinearLayout around all 4 buttons, make the LinearLayout WRAP_CONTENT highet, and the buttons themselves MATCH_PARENT height.  Now all 4 buttons will be the same height-  the height of the largest one.  You should be able to write your layouts to do this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting height for button just remove listener from observer like

```
ViewTreeObserver observer= Button0.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    int HighestButton;
                    HighestButton = Button0.getHeight();
                    Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 0");
                    if(Button1.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button1.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 1");
                    }
                    if(Button2.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button2.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 2");
                    }
                    if(Button3.getHeight() > HighestButton){
                        HighestButton = Button3.getHeight();
                        Log.d("HighestButton", HighestButton+ " 3");
                    }

                    Button0.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button1.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button2.setHeight(HighestButton);
                    Button3.setHeight(HighestButton);

                    if (observer.isAlive()) {
                        observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = Button0.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    if(Button1.getHeight() > Button0.getHeight()){
                        Button0.setHeight(Button1.getHeight());
                    }

                    if(Button2.getHeight() > Button1.getHeight()){
                        Button0.setHeight(Button2.getHeight());
                        Button1.setHeight(Button2.getHeight());
                    }

                    if(Button3.getHeight() > Button2.getHeight()){
                        Button0.setHeight(Button3.getHeight());
                        Button1.setHeight(Button3.getHeight());
                        Button2.setHeight(Button3.getHeight());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: If i use this kind of solution for the other buttons everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with Dynamically changing text ? you call set text in your buttons,

so i think u can do it just after setting text without ViewTreeObserver

Comment: I receive the text for the Buttons from a Database which brings the possibility of different text lengths and I already solved the problem with the height